# Propagation of jquery/ajax promises in Durandal

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, durandal

I am using durandal.. I have a base controller that manage the calls to the server... every controller, specialized per use case, use the base controller to do the call to the server.
In the base controller I have this code:

```
self.call = function (url, type, data, success) {
    return Q.when(
        $.ajax({
            ...
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                   // Do some work
                }
            }
        })
     );
```

Then, in my specialized controller I have

```
myController.execute(command)
      .then(function () {
            //Do work ok
       })
        .fail(function (data) {
             //Manage error
       });
```

the execute method, internally call the `call` method I wrote at the start... 
The problem of this solution is that when I manage the error in the base controller, then I execute also the `fail` code in the specialized controller...

Another way I tried... in the base controller

```
self.call = function (url, type, data, success) {
    return Q.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
             app.showError("a new error");
        }
         else 
             throw { "jqXHR": jqXHR, "textStatus": textStatus, "errorThrown": errorThrown };
    });
```

In this case, the `then` code is executed in the specialized controller. How can I avoid to stop the propagation of the promise in this case?

Thank you

Comment: In order to keep propagating the error (causing the `.then` fulfillment handlers not to execute) you can rethrow the error.

Comment: No... I want to stop the propagation

Comment: What are `Q.when` and `Q.fail`, are you using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/)?

Comment: yes.. perhaps the correct question is how to stop the propagation of Q "promise"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
myController.execute(command)
      .then(function () {
            //Do work ok
       })
        .fail(function (data) {
             //Manage error
       });
```

You should do this:

```
myController.execute(command)
      .then(function (data) {
            //Do work ok
       }, function (reason) {
            //error handled 
            //you need to manully throw error here if you want the error to be propagated
            //throw reason; 
       });
```

**UPDATE**
You don't have to wrap jquery promise with q, here's another approach:

```
self.call = function (url, type, data, success) {
  var result = Q.defer();

  $.ajax({
     success: function (data) {
        result.resolve(data);
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
          console.log('error 500, handled');
       } else {
          result.reject(textStatus);
       }
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

This way you may "propagate" you error conditionally, though I wouldn't recommend this, because pending promises (neither resolved or rejected) may be a potential source of memory leaks.

Comment: No... I think I haven't been clear in explaining my problem.. someone also changed the title that I think is now wrong... I have a centralized point where I manage the call to server... If I obtain an error 500 I want to manage the error in this point, that is centralized (when I do `Q.when` or `Q.fail`) .... In all other  cases, I want to propagate the error in the `fail` of  `myController`....
To be more clear... I want to go in the `fail` or in the `function(reason)` of `myController` just when it's not an error 500

Comment: Are you aware that you can set up a global jQuery ajax error handler? You can have local error handlers and rethrow anything you don't want to process in the local handler.